# Persuading Solve to accept prime parameter

Tags: equation-solving

The following evaluation:

```
Solve[
   a > 0 && d > 0 && k > 0 && a*d + k == 1691 && (1691 - d) == (a - 1)*d + k
   , {a, d, k}
   , Integers
  ]
```

gives me plenty of solutions but, how can I persuade Solve to restrict (1691 - d) to be prime? For instance; I'm seeking a solution `a=14; d=120; k=11;` so that `(1691-d)=1571` is prime.  Thank you.

Comment: Did any of the answers satisfied your need? There are **[things to do after your question is answered](https://wolfr.am/v57DB3p4)**. It's a good idea to stay vigilant for some time, better approaches may come later improving over previous replies. Experienced users may point alternatives, caveats or limitations. New users should **test answers before [voting](https://wolfr.am/v57ItzJq)** and **wait 24 hours before [accepting](https://wolfr.am/v57LwTXD)** the best one. One weeks is enough wait. Participation is essential for the site, please do your part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplest is to merely select from your earlier solutions:

```
mysols = Solve[
      a > 0 && 
      d > 0 && 
      k > 0 && 
      a d + k == 1691 && 
      (1691 - d) == (a - 1) d + k, 
   {a, d, k}, 
   Integers];
Select[mysols, PrimeQ[1691 - #[[2, 2]]] &]
```

Comment: Thank you David. I wish that FindInstance[expr, vars,dom,n] would also have Primes as a domain, so that I could restrict the number of solutions more efficiently.

Answer (score 2):

Edit: My first attempt of putting the PrimeQ command in the equation itself wasn't working. This should be ok:

```
sol = Solve[
  a > 0 && d > 0 && k > 0 && 
   a*d + k == 1691 && (1691 - d) == (a - 1)*d + k, {a, d, k}, Integers]

Select[sol, PrimeQ[1691 - d /. #] &]
```